# How do you shift first valid value to the left?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to change a dataframe that's ordered by calendar year to years past.

```
id 2015  2016   2017 2018   2019
0   NaN  7.0    8.0  7.0    3.0
1   NaN  8.0    5.0  7.0    NaN
2   4.0  NaN    5.0  NaN    NaN
3   5.0  4.0    3.0  9.0    NaN
4   NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN    1.0
5   4.0  3.0    NaN  4.0    5.0
```

I need to shift all valid values left to the first column.

The expected result should look like this:

```
id   Y1   Y2      Y3     Y4  Y5
0   7.0  8.0     7.0    3.0  NaN
1   8.0  5.0     7.0    NaN  NaN
2   4.0  NaN     5.0    NaN  NaN
3   5.0  4.0     3.0    9.0  NaN
4   1.0  NaN     NaN    NaN  NaN
5   4.0  3.0     NaN    4.0  5.0
```

Note: "id" is a column, not the index.

Comment: Null values between actual numbers should be kept.

Comment: Is your `id` column your index or an actual column?

Comment: It's an actual column

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try a row-wise application of `np.roll`:

```
df = df.set_index('id')
# using @user3483203's argmax trick to optimize
df.apply(lambda x: np.roll(x, -(~np.isnan(x)).argmax()), axis=1, raw=True)

    2015  2016  2017  2018  2019
id                              
0    7.0   8.0   7.0   3.0   NaN
1    8.0   5.0   7.0   NaN   NaN
2    4.0   NaN   5.0   NaN   NaN
3    5.0   4.0   3.0   9.0   NaN
4    1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
5    4.0   3.0   NaN   4.0   5.0
```

Unfortunately, `np.roll` isn't vectorised to perform different shifts for separate rows, and in the interest of preserving NaNs between values, this will have to do.

Answer (score 5):

You can operate on the underlying numpy array using `ogrid` and indexing.

```
u = df.set_index('id').values
x, y = u.shape
r, c = np.ogrid[:x, :y]
m = (~np.isnan(u)).argmax(1)
cix = c + m[:, None]
cix[cix >= y] -= y
u[r, cix]
```

```
array([[ 7.,  8.,  7.,  3., nan],
       [ 8.,  5.,  7., nan, nan],
       [ 4., nan,  5., nan, nan],
       [ 5.,  4.,  3.,  9., nan],
       [ 1., nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [ 4.,  3., nan,  4.,  5.]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Find the shift for each row, then apply the shifts in groups:

```
df = df.set_index('id')

# Required shift for each row
n = df.isnull()
s = (n*n.cumprod(1)).sum(1)*-1

for shift, idx in s.groupby(s).groups.items():
    df.loc[idx, :] = df.loc[idx].shift(shift, axis=1)

df.columns = [f'Y{i+1}' for i in range(df.shape[1])]
df = df.reset_index()
```

#### Output:

```
   id   Y1   Y2   Y3   Y4   Y5
0   0  7.0  8.0  7.0  3.0  NaN
1   1  8.0  5.0  7.0  NaN  NaN
2   2  4.0  NaN  5.0  NaN  NaN
3   3  5.0  4.0  3.0  9.0  NaN
4   4  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5   5  4.0  3.0  NaN  4.0  5.0
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using `first_valid_index`:

```
df = df.set_index('id')
df.apply(lambda x: x.shift(-x.index.get_loc(x.first_valid_index())), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    2015  2016  2017  2018  2019
id                              
0    7.0   8.0   7.0   3.0   NaN
1    8.0   5.0   7.0   NaN   NaN
2    4.0   NaN   5.0   NaN   NaN
3    5.0   4.0   3.0   9.0   NaN
4    1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
5    4.0   3.0   NaN   4.0   5.0
```

#### Details

First, `apply` using `axis=1`, this will apply a function on each row.

Using `first_valid_index` to find the index of the first non-null value in a pd.Series.  Remember, the pd.Series in this case is each row of the dataframe.

Next, use `get_loc` to determine the integer location of this index.

And, finally, use `shift` to move the values of that pd.Series backwards by the integer location in the pd.Series index.

---

And, you can add second line to rename columns

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.shift(-x.index.get_loc(x.first_valid_index())), axis=1)\
  .set_axis(['Y'+str(i) for i in range(1, df.shape[1]+1)], axis=1, inplace=False)
```

Output:

```
     Y1   Y2   Y3   Y4   Y5
id                         
0   7.0  8.0  7.0  3.0  NaN
1   8.0  5.0  7.0  NaN  NaN
2   4.0  NaN  5.0  NaN  NaN
3   5.0  4.0  3.0  9.0  NaN
4   1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5   4.0  3.0  NaN  4.0  5.0
```